# How to select subset of metrics to log on commandline when using model.fit() in Keras & Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have added lots of metrics for tracking the performance of my multi-class segmentation model in Keras and `Tensorflow`. These metrics include class-wise and aggregated metric functions. Now Tensorboard contains everything I want, but my command line output looks overloaded now. I would like to remove the class-wise metrics from the command line output while keeping them in Tensorboard. Is that possible?

```
model.compile(loss=dice_loss, 
              metrics=[f1score, f1score_class0, f1score_class1, f1score_class2])
```

Is it possible when implementing `train_step` and `test_step` on my own? Would I need to implement the training loop from scratch?

Comment: Most probably, it should be `model.compile`, not `model.fit`.

Comment: @IvanK. You're right.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done using callbacks. Namely:

1. write a callback printing only the metrics you are interested in. On how to write callbacks, see [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_callback#a_basic_example).
2. in `model.fit` set `verbose=0` and add your callback to `callbacks`.
3. run the training.

As far as I know, tensorboard uses all logs. Hence it will get all metrics from all epoches.

If you do not need any information to be printed during training at all, you may just set `verbose=0`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of Ivan K. I came up with another idea:

The `keras.callbacks.ProgbarLogger` is responsible for logging to the command line.
It is possible to subclass the `ProgbarLogger` of keras and add an `ProgbarLogger` to the callbacks. It will prevent Keras to add the default `ProgbarLogger` and therefore replace it. Just implement all methods receiving the logs as argument, filter the logs and pass the filtered logs to the corresponding parent's class method.

This example removes logs which contain substrings in `opt_out` list.

```
import tensorflow as tf
class CustomProgbarLogger(tf.keras.callbacks.ProgbarLogger):
    def __init__(self, count_mode="samples", stateful_metrics=None, opt_out=[]):
        super().__init__(count_mode=count_mode, stateful_metrics=stateful_metrics)
        self.opt_out = opt_out

    def _filter(self, logname):
        return all(word not in logname for word in self.opt_out)

    def _filter_logs(self, logs):
        return logs and {key: value for key, value in logs.items() if self._filter(key)}

    def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        super().on_train_batch_end(batch, self._filter_logs(logs))

    def on_test_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        super().on_test_batch_end(batch, self._filter_logs(logs))

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        super().on_epoch_end(epoch, self._filter_logs(logs))

    def on_test_end(self, logs=None):
        super().on_test_end(self._filter_logs(logs))

    def on_predict_end(self, logs=None):
        super().on_predict_end(self._filter_logs(logs))
```

this example will remove every log containing one of the string `class`, `precision`, `recall` in the key.

```
progbar_callback = CustomProgbarLogger(opt_out=["class", "precision", "recall"])
model.fit(dataset, callbacks=[progbar_callback, tensorboard_callback])
```